# Why not to style <button> as .btn by default?

Tags: html, css

So my question is simple but yet I haven't been able to find any source that explains it:

**Why do libraries require you to add extra classes with the same name as the element they style?**

Many use the terminology `<button class="btn">` or `<button class="button">`. Then if we want to make it the primary button, we add the `btn-primary` instead of just `primary`.

I am the creator of [Picnic CSS](http://picnicss.com/) and I haven't really found any issue when *not* doing this. But I am sure that many smarter people than me know better, and when everyone keeps doing the same I start to wonder the reason.

Example of libraries that do this:

- [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) by Twitter
- [Pure CSS](http://purecss.io/) by Yahoo
- [Min CSS](http://mincss.com)
- [Bass CSS](http://www.basscss.com)
- [Milligram](http://milligram.github.io/)

Libraries that *somewhat* do this:

- [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/): they do this only for subclasses such as `button-primary`.

Libraries that do *not* follow this:

- [Picnic CSS](http://picnicss.com/) (my own)

EDIT:

The question is not *why the class is defined*, but it is *why isn't `<button>` given a default style that matches `.btn`?* This could be done easily:

```
button, input[type="submit"], .button {
  /* styles */
}
```

Comment: In case you want to use it on other elements.

Comment: lol I think I asked it wrong, I am not saying *not* to define also `.btn`, but why not defaulting `<button>` to the same style as `.btn`: `button, input[type=submit], .button { /* styles */ }`

Comment: Because that would add a lot of duplicate selectors.

Comment: Because then you have the option if you don't want to style a button the default way you can style it another way. Instead of using !important or other ways to overrule.

Comment: I think it's just trying to avoid mistakes of using element selector `button` or class `.button`, and `.btn` is obviously shorter to write. For why using `btn-primary` instead of `primary`, I guess it's always good to avoid chained classes, such as `.btn.primary{}`.

Comment: I am voting to close this as opinionated as it will do nothing but attract speculative answers.  The only people who can answer this question for sure are the authors of their respective frameworks.

Comment: @cimmanon well that comment is also speculative, so all js questions should be closed because only ECMAScript committe can answer it? I would love to know the reason(s), which I think might be 1 or 2, so I think it's not so opinionated

Comment: "Why did someone design something this way" is speculative.

Comment: That's my point exactly, all languages are *designed*. However I understand that this might be *too specific* so only the few people designing the specific libraries might know, so I'll close the question and ask to those libraries. Thank you (:

Comment: Off topic, but the selectors for the various buttons in your CSS are not very consistent. sometimes you include `input[type='reset'], input[type='button']` but usually you don't. This causes different buttons to look differently with your stylesheet, where they would look uniformly alike without it.

Answer (score 9):

The reason behind this is because the `btn` class can be used for `<a>`  and `<input>` elements too. Take [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) for example.

```
<button class="btn">Button</button>
<input type="submit" class="btn" />
<a href="#" class="btn"></a>
```

These all produce the same appearing buttons, but you can use them in any way you wish.

Comment: I updated it, I'm not asking why not to define a class .btn`, but why isn't button styled as `.btn` by default, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Because it would require an extra selector.

Comment: default styling `<button>` forces the developer to undo it with CSS if he/she wants a different look, as opposed to just not including the class.

Comment: But it's 1 extra selector in the css vs dozens of extra classes in the html

Comment: @leftside that's a fair point, so it'd be about it not being *prescriptive* or *invasive* that I call it in Picnic CSS, right?

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia You do make an interesting point, actually. I suppose what leftside is saying is correct too. If the user wants to display a native button for whatever reason (not that they should, it's bad UX) they can simply remove the class.

Comment: `<input type="submit" class="btn" />` I don't think this is used often. Mostly you just see <button> which defaults to submit. But yeah, re-using it in both `<a>` and `<button>` seems like the best argument.